# OSError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

When I try to open `.h5` file, it shows the following error

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2869, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-524e5789c66b>", line 6, in <module>
    f = h5py.File(filename, 'r+')
  File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 394, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Users\VW3ZTWS\PycharmProjects\Data_Collection_and_learnings\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 172, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '28ggv-016.h5.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 1, o_flags = 2)
```

Code I used:

```html
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filename = '28ggv-016.h5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: have you tried using the full path to the file ?

Comment: Probably could not find the file. Give the full path, double check it exists where you think it should.

Comment: Yes when i give the absolute path it reads !!!! @reportgunner
But what is the reason, for not opening directly ?

Comment: you are most likely executing the script from a directory different than the `.h5` file

Comment: @ponraj.rajesh did the answer posted below helped? If it did you may accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl + Shift + C` to copy the complete path of the file and paste it inside your `filename`:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filename = 'dir:\your\path\to\the\file\28ggv-016.h5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
```